# What is the origin and / or standardness of the term "bang account"?

Tags: active-directory, windows

I keep hearing "bang account" at my company and, through context, figured it out to mean an account with elevated privileges.

I believe this is particularly the case with Active Directory accounts, but I can find very, very few mentions of "bang account", "bang-account" or variations of that term on the internet.

My only context for "bang" is the beginning of shell scripts "hash bang bin bash" for example: `#!/bin/bash`. I suppose in some ways `!` could be shorthand for an "elevated" account.

Could anyone tell me if I'm right, where it comes from (surely it has some etymological meaning), and if it is actually scoped to just AD?

Comment: I've never heard that.  "hash-bang" yes.

Comment: Why don't you ask your cow-orkers - surely they'll know.

Comment: Why not just ask the person/people using the term?

Comment: Another vote for "never heard this usage."

Comment: @Iain the response I got (when I asked in the moment) was: "That's standard at this company." Pretty irritating...

Comment: I Googled "bang account" and got nothing but adult "dating" sites.  Certainly nothing to indicate it's a common term as it pertains to Windows user accounts.

Comment: @quadruplebucky I've only heard of `#!` as *Sharp Bang*

Comment: http://www.catb.org/jargon/html/B/bang.html

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Google-FU

...it appears to be something on an academic nomenclature level

There are a few others such as:

http://tech.its.iastate.edu/win2000/admin/WinAdmin.2010.07.09.pdf

http://www.eng.uwaterloo.ca/~erick/nexus/useridconventions.html

> Sometimes users are given 'elevated' privileges, which might be the
>   ability to change passwords for a group of users, or the ability to
>   administer certain machines.
>
> In the case of a research group, the elevated privileges might be
>   finely tuned permissions to just perform the actions needed on
>   particular userids and/or computers.
>
> In the case of a departmental or faculty computing office resource
>   person, the elevated privilege would have access to the entire portion
>   of the active directory tree that is co-managed by that individual.
>
> **These are referred to as BANG accounts, and they take the format of
>   exclamation mark followed by uwuserid.  E.g.. !jblow, !j2smith.**
>
> Beginning with Windows 2000, the most effective way to elevate a
>   user's capabilities is to leverage permissions of the active
>   directory.  We can fine tune the permissions to entirely (but not
>   excessively) cover the actions this elevated user is expected to
>   perform.
>
> The NT 4 style of elevation is to add the user to the local
>   administrators' group, but with Active Directory it is easier to group
>   the stations in to an OU and assign the privilege at the OU level.

And here: http://micronet-at-uc-berkeley.840177.n3.nabble.com/Micronet-bang-account-on-AD-not-behaving-td1748226.html

Comment: I found this same article, but it didn't seem relevant as I can say for certain that no one at my company (<15 years) has any ties to Berkeley or University of Waterloo.

These two articles were the ONLY mentions of this term, and I couldn't make any connection to how the term had made the jump to my company.

It must be coming from another source?

Comment: There are a few others such as: http://tech.its.iastate.edu/win2000/admin/WinAdmin.2010.07.09.pdf ...it appears to be something on an academic nomenclature level.

Comment: `it appears to be something on an academic nomenclature level`  
This is the only connection I can make as the person standardizing this term comes from a university background.

Answer (score 3):

Some quick googling shows that this comes from some Unix cultures at some universities. Thus, I would say it's not widespread, certainly not a standard, and not usually used with AD.

It refers to the practice of beginning a username (for a privileged account) with a "!", pronounced "bang."

Answer (score 0):

So I just ran into this question while searching for an event ID for Win Ser 2008. Just in case any one else is still in question about Bang account.  A bang account is merely a way of granting and tracking people that have/need access to certain resources. Since most of these are administrator accounts, A specific Admin might just need rights to access one additional resource that the rest of the admins generally do not need. In this case a specific bang account might be created, just for that user. It also works vice versa if one admin just needs limited/strict permissions, just so there's no risk of potentially causing havoc with the domain.